# Пустое поле в конце TableView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

у меня есть TableView на ViewController в которой отображаются данные в зависимости от выбранного режима. Выбрав первый режим данные отображаются корректно. Выбрав второй режим в конце таблицы, после всех ячеек появляется пустое поле. Это не пустые ячейки. 
numberOfSections корректный, как и numberOfRowsInSection.

[image]

[image]

Ссылка на класс https://yadi.sk/d/IkSsYBu2tZRYm

Comment: вы б уже тогда весь проект выложили, по одному этому классу сильно не разберешься

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что после смены контента tableView, таблица пытается сохранить Scroll и дорисовывает внизу дополнительное пространство, как если создать таблицу на весь экран с 3 ячейками, то она дорисует дополнительные ячейки, чтобы таблица отрисовывалась до конца экрана. Единственный нормальный выход из ситуации на мой взгляд - создать две отдельные tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был задан давно, но т.к эта проблема с несуществующими ячейками таблицы в iOS разработке встречается очень часто, напишу решение.

Наиболее простой способ избавиться от пустых ячеек такой:

Swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Objective-C:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```